# Exhaustive feature selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to select the best features for my model using exhaustive feature selection but i got an IndexError and i have been trying to figure it out.

```
X = train.columns.difference(['Customer_ID', 'total_claim_amount'])
y = train['total_claim_amount']
# exhaustive feature selection
from mlxtend.feature_selection import ExhaustiveFeatureSelector as EFS
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

feature_selector = EFS(rf_model,min_features=2, max_features=23, scoring='accuracy', print_progress=True, cv=5)

feature_selector.fit(X, y)
```

the error i got is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-6c2f49995b6c> in <module>
      7 feature_selector = EFS(rf_model,min_features=2, max_features=23, scoring='accuracy', print_progress=True, cv=5)
      8 
----> 9 feature_selector.fit(X, y)
     10 
     11 print('Best R2 score: %.2f' % feature_selector.best_score_ * (-1))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\feature_selection\exhaustive_feature_selector.py in fit(self, X, y, custom_feature_names, groups, **fit_params)
    225 
    226         if (not isinstance(self.max_features, int) or
--> 227                 (self.max_features > X.shape[1] or self.max_features < 1)):
    228             raise AttributeError('max_features must be'
    229                                  ' smaller than %d and larger than 0' %

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

The only tuple index in the line from the last trace is `X.shape[1]`, which indicates that your `X` is only 1-dimensional. And indeed,

```py
train.columns.difference(...)
```

just gives the *list of column names*, not the dataframe restricted to those columns. You want

```py
X = train[train.columns.difference(...)]
```

(or maybe `train.drop(...)` is easier to parse).

Comment: I did this but I'm getting a Value error saying 'continuous not supported', does EFS not work for regression.

Comment: It should.  Please post a new question, including the full traceback for the new error.

Comment: I changed scoring from accuracy to 'r2' and it seems to be working. Its been running for almost an hour now.

Answer (score -1):

The parameter for the maximum number of features for the feature selection is not allowed to exceed your overall number of features of your data. The constraint for it to work is to fulfill: `max_features <= X.shape[1]`. What you could do is to set the maximum number of features to be the number of features of your data.

```
feature_selector = EFS(max_features=X.shape[1], ...)
```

Comment: I did, but it still gave out the same error